# In C++, are s[i] - '0' and atoi() same?

Tags: c++, string, atoi

Are `atoi()` and `s[i] - '0'` same?

```
int countSubstrings(string s, int n)
{
    int count = 0, sum = 0;

    unordered_map<int, int> mp;
    mp[0]++;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {

        sum += (s[i] - '0');
          cout << sum << endl;
        count += mp[sum - (i + 1)];
        ++mp[sum - (i + 1)];
    }
    return count;
```

In the above code, can we use the `atoi()` function instead of using `s[i] - '0'`?

Comment: `atoi()` is for converting a multi-character string to a number, `s[i] - '0'` is only for a single digit.

Comment: Do you mean replacing exactly `s[i]-0` with `atoi`? The entire loop is doing more than just converting a string to an int.

Comment: No, you cannot. Because the loop makes the sum of each single char in the string, instead atoi will compute the value of a whole string (`c_str()`).

Comment: Or [std::from_chars](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/from_chars) if you want to be the coolest kid in class.

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't replace it like that.

The argument to `atoi()` must be a C-style null-terminated string. `s[i]` is a single character, not a string. So if you wanted to use `atoi()` you would first have to create a string to hold the character.

```
char digit[2] = "";
digit[0] = s[i];
sum += atoi(digit);
```